# Rank of the top Chow group

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes, intersection-theory

Let $X$ be a regular integal scheme of finite type over $\mathbb Z$ and assume that $X$ has dimension $d$. In general it is not known if the Chow groups $CH^q(X)$ ($q$ is the codimension) are finitely generated abelian groups. It is a widely open conjecture that the Chow groups are indeed finitely generated. (This is actually not true for varieties over $\mathbb C$, since we have Mumford example for surfaces).

We only have an affirmative answer to the conjecture in the following cases:

1. Any $X$ and $q=1,d$. So for divisors and $0$-cycles
2. When $X$ has an affine stratification (or cellular decomposition in the sense of "Fulton- Intersection theory" example 1.9.1); for any $q$. In this case we can even compute the generators.

The fact that $CH^d(X)$ is finitely generated follows by some argument of $K$-theory, but my question is the following:

> Do we have any case (not included in 1.) where we can say what is the rank of $CH^d(X)$? Is it computable?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by not in 1/2? Take some scheme for which the Chow groups are completely known (like a suitable elliptic curve). Put it inside projective space and take the blow up of the projective space along it. The Chow groups of the blown-up variety should be computable.